# Refactoring Javascript "extract method" in Eclipse causes a crash

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, jsdt, nodeclipse

I have the nodeclipse plugin installed in Eclipse Juno, and I would like to use the "extract Method" function to refactor some JavaScript, however I get the following exception in ".log" in the workspace ".metadata" directory. I have the feeling that I have conflicting versions of plugins, eclipse or JVM. How can I solve this?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 4 10000 2013-06-12 09:12:10.534
!MESSAGE Internal Error
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.run(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.createChange(RefactoringWizard.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.computeUserInputSuccessorPage(RefactoringWizard.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.UserInputWizardPage.computeSuccessorPage(UserInputWizardPage.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.UserInputWizardPage.getNextPage(UserInputWizardPage.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.nextOrPreviewPressed(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.access$2(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2$1.widgetSelected(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.RefactoringStarter.activate(RefactoringStarter.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.actions.ExtractMethodAction.run(ExtractMethodAction.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.ChildPropertyDescriptor cannot be cast to org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.ChildListPropertyDescriptor
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.code.ExtractMethodRefactoring.createChange(ExtractMethodRefactoring.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CreateChangeOperation.run(CreateChangeOperation.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Root exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.ChildPropertyDescriptor cannot be cast to org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.ChildListPropertyDescriptor
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.code.ExtractMethodRefactoring.createChange(ExtractMethodRefactoring.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CreateChangeOperation.run(CreateChangeOperation.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactoring Javascript is pure Eclipse JSDT functionality.
Before raising bug on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/), can you try to reproduse the bug in Eclipse Juno or better Eclipse Kepler http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php

Comment: Bug reported here for those who would like to follow or vote for it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377383